# Detect Double byte characters

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have to write a JavaScript function that will validate if the entered text is in Double Byte.The text box should accept only double byte Japanese characters, double byte English characters and double byte special characters. I tried using a number of solutions offered in other blogs but the validation fired either for single byte English or single byte Japanese characters i.e validation fired fine for single byte English characters and failed for single byte Japanese.

Comment: I believe `"string".charCodeAt(index)` (for each character) should return a number > 127

Comment: i used function 
isDoubleByte(str) {
    for (var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 255) { return true; }
    } 
    return false;
}
if (!isDoubleByte(str)) {
    alert("Validation failed");
}
but this runs only for english single byte. when i enter japanese, the validation msg does not pop up

Comment: Isn't that what you want..? If you enter japanese it shouldn't fail, so it's good to not get the alert

Comment: can you at least provide some string examples?

Comment: system should accept ＩＣ but not IC. This text can be appended with double byte Japanese characters like 着 but not single byte Japanese characters like  ｩ

Answer (score 1):

Characters can be single byte ,double byte, triple byte and so on. So single byte follows in a particular range. Same thing is true for other characters.Based on this I have created following functions that will calculate the size of a string on the basis of memory

```
function getByteLength(normal_val) {
    // Force string type
    normal_val = String(normal_val);

    var byteLen = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < normal_val.length; i++) {
        var c = normal_val.charCodeAt(i);
        byteLen +=  c < (1 <<  7) ? 1 :
                c < (1 << 11) ? 2 :
                c < (1 << 16) ? 3 :
                c < (1 << 21) ? 4 :
                c < (1 << 26) ? 5 :
                c < (1 << 31) ? 6 : Number.NaN;
     }
     return byteLen;
}
```

I have created a js fiddle that will determine the size of entered text in terms of memory.

http://jsfiddle.net/paraselixir/d83oaa3v/5/

Here in your case you can use the memory size of the string to determine double byte  -

so if string has x characters and memory size is x then all characters are single bytes
if string has x characters and memory size is 2x then all characters are double bytes.
if string has x characters and memory size is in between x and 2x then all characters are a combination of single and double bytes.